# Java video chat web application

Tags: java, flash, video-streaming, p2p

First off all I should say that I don't have good knowledge in this area and I don't ask to give me a full solution of my problem, but I'm really hoping for any kind of your help (suggestions, useful recourses to read etc).
Here is my case:

What I want to do : I want to develop simple Java WEB application with video chat. I want give its users an opportunity to call to another users and have a conversation. The conversation must be only between two people at one room at a time (no more). The website will have profiles of many users and they will be able to communicate via video chat. I used to want to make it p2p, but now I have some doubts and if I could simplify my work by using any of streaming servers, I'd choose it.

What experience I've got now: I have experience in working with Java, HTML, JavaScript, little experience in Spring Framework, Hibernate, Maven.

Another information: I want to make it as simple as possible. I even don't want to use frameworks like Spring, I'd better use pure servlets and jsp. I have only a little time to do it, that is why I'd prefer to use only Java technologies (like servlets, applets) rather than use other technologies (like Flash). But I don't know whether I can do it without Flash. Anyway I could learn other technologies if they were very important to succeed.

Please give me some suggestions what to use and what to read to find a clear vision.

Comment: Oh, dear. Where video comes in, "simple" goes out. Check out xuggler: http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler

Comment: OK not "simple", but I want to get some tips to investigate this area

Comment: It's pretty hard to find any codecs in pure java. Mostly you'll end up with some VLC stuff, Live555 or the like wrapped for use in Java. A lot of native programming, really bad docus (no docu is bad docu) ...

Comment: I don't really see how a java web app goes into this. You should separate you web application from the "video chat" and go for some complete package for the video. It's nowhere near simple.

Comment: If that's an option, I second Petter, +1